# How can I access a variable that is imported on another <script> tag in JS

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

I was messing around with socket.io and I've encountered to a problem that I couldn't solve for awhile. I have a HTML page that has 2 different scripts imported. One of them is the socket.io import;

```
<script src="node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js">
    var socket;
    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080'); 
</script>
```

And the other one is a script for that does stuff for the game. I want to call the variable "socket" that was declared in the first imported script, (that is above) in this script. And FYI it's inside of a function just like this;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunc(data) {
        socket.emit('key',data);
    }
</script>
```

Now if I try to run it like this, it says the "socket" variable is not defined. If I try to use the game script inside the socket.io script, it doesn't work either. And I don't know if there's any way that I could import the socket.io script inside the game script so what should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure if browsers will execute the first script, as the script tag has a `src` attribute.  See [If a script element has a src attribute specified, it should not have a script embedded inside its tags.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

Comment: Let try a function myFunc(socket, data) as parameters to see, no sure about the result :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a script tag use both a source and have something inside it. Put your socket.io source script in its own script tag and it should work.

EDIT: Like this:

```
<script src="node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket;
    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080'); 
</script>
```

Comment: It's not in same script tag. There's 2 different script tags that are included to the page.

Comment: In the first script, you have both a `src` attribute and text inside the tag. That is not ok. You have to put them in separate script tags like I showed above